# How to use fixed length CCSID 37 char value in where clause of sql select for IBM DB2 iSeries in node.js

Tags: java, database, db2

My application is connected to IBM DB2 iSeries database connected through DataDirect approach using db2.jar in Java. When I run any select query with specific data in where clause it do not detect the value that I pass in where condition. Data type for that column is of CHAR(7) and I am passing a value as 'P544901'. How can I use this or any other 7 char value and db can detect it. Is there any other process that can solve my problem.

Sample Code in Java  -

```
String sql = "SELECT poMast.ORDNO  from AMFLIBL.POMAST AS poMast WHERE poMast.ORDNO =  ? ";
Class.forName("com.ddtek.jdbc.db2.DB2Driver");
String url = "jdbc:datadirect:db2://hostname:port;DatabaseName=dbName;";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username","password");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, 'P544901');
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
System.out.println("ResultSet : \n");
System.out.println(" VNDNO");
while (rs.next())
{
   System.out.println(rs.getString("ORDNO"));
}
```

Comment: double quotes??

Comment: If I will put double quotes it will become String and mismatch with data type described in database

Answer (score 0):

try to modify like this (replace simple quote by double quote)

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "P544901");
```